# Running Mysql after removing macports etc

Tags: mysql, installation, mac-osx

I used to use macports.. awhile ago.. I finally for other reasons uninstalled it.

Now.. fully gone/cleaned up/nothong of it on the system..

if I download Mysql isntall package.. or try to use homebrew.. anything.. on startup I get:

```
s:~ rs$ sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql
110707 21:52:47 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/rs.local.err'.
mkdir: /opt/local/var/run: No such file or directory
chown: /opt/local/var/run/mysql5: No such file or directory
chmod: /opt/local/var/run/mysql5: No such file or directory
110707 21:52:47 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
110707 21:52:48 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/rs.local.pid ended
```

What on planet earth is having a downloaded from the mysql main site.. having it "look at" /opt/local (macports land)

I can't figure out WHY it would *ever* want to look at /opt/local if it is the downloaded mysql etc etc

thoughts?

I basically can't, with homebrew or a mysql.com downoad/install package.. *ever* get and start mysql.

maddening!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mdfind` to locate any errant MySQL configuration files. It is the command-line equivalent of Spotlight for OS X. This search is very fast.

```
mdfind -name my.cnf
```

If that doesn't locate anything, try using classic `find`. The following command will search the entire filesystem, including any mounted external drives or network shares. I recommend unmounting them before continuing. This search is exhaustive and may take a while.

```
find / -name my.cnf
```

If you find one, delete it or look inside to see where the data paths are pointing. Keep in mind that my.cnf can reside in a [number of locations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html#id401777):

```
/etc/my.cnf            Global options
/etc/mysql/my.cnf      Global options (as of MySQL 5.1.15)
SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf      Global options
$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf     Server-specific options
defaults-extra-file    The file specified with --defaults-extra-file=path, if any
~/.my.cnf              User-specific options
```